# How to find a specific number in any position of a string

Tags: python

```
import math

import random

a = random.random()

b = random.random()

c = random.random()

d = a*b*c

e = 14

print ("a = {0}".format(a))

print ("b = {0}".format(b))

print ("c = {0}".format(c))

print ("d = {0}".format(d))

if "e" in d:

    print("Value found")

else:

    print("Value not found")
```

The problems is the variable `e`.

Comment: What do you mean: I want to find a number in any position?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if "e" in d:
```

with:

```
if str(e) in str(d):
```

Demo:

```
>>> e=12
>>> d=45123
>>> str(e) in str(d)
True
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first convert your integers to strings for doing like a string-like search, like:

```
if str(e) in str(d):
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by following this way:

```
list=[]
for x in range(2,d):
    if d%x==0:
        list.append(x)
if e in list:
    print ("e is a multiplier")
else:
   print("e is not a multiplier")
```